# get current path of the .app file being executed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I get the current path of my .app which is being executed in cocoa mac application?

I tried using NSTask to do pwd but returns me /

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it by using [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]